# Hive splits ORC files on small parts

Tags: hive, hdfs

```
create table n_data(MARKET string,CATEGORY string,D map<string,string>,monthid int,value  DOUBLE)
  STORED AS ORC
 ;
```

I load data into it (over 45000000 rows), look at hive warehouse

[image]

Result table consists of 5 files with 10MB-20MB size, but **dfs.block.size** sets to 128MB, it's not optimal to store small files, because it uses whole block!

How to setup HIVE split files by 128 MB?

**EDIT**
insert query:

```
insert into n_data
select tmp.market,tmp.category,d,adTable.monthid,tmp.factperiod[adTable.monthid] as fact 
from (select market,category,d,factperiod,map_keys(factperiod) as month_arr  from n_src where market is not null) as tmp 
LATERAL VIEW explode(month_arr) adTable AS monthid
```

Comment: How are you inserting the records, show insert statement. Do you have any other property related to hive settings?

Comment: @Ambrish I add Insert query in the question

Comment: @Ambrish  No I don't have other related to hive settings

Comment: *insert into* will create new file with every run. So if you are running your tool in batch then you will see at least BATCH_COUNT number of files.

Comment: @Ambrish, I run insert into only ones, when loading fact, it doesn't runs in the batch mode

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the following config parameters for hive:

```
hive.merge.mapfiles = true
hive.merge.mapredfiles = true
hive.merge.tezfiles = true
hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize = 16000000
```

I had the exact same problem, until I found [this source](http://qnalist.com/questions/5993258/merge-small-orc-files). You can try setting these params manually in a hive session by using the "set" command like this:

```
set hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=16000000;
```

If you just type "set;" in a hive session console, you can check if the above mentioned params where set correctly. After testing, I recommend changing them in your hive-site.xml config file or via Ambari (If you're using the Hortonworksdistribution). Cheers!